# Show results from form in a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I am new to this, so please be patient :).

I have a form like this (**echoing from php file**):

```
<form id= \"myForm\" class=\"friendForm\" action=\"messages.php\" method=\"GET\" > 
        <input class=\"friendInput\" type=\"text\" name=\"idprijemce\" value='$idprijemce' hidden>  
        <input class=\"friendSubmit\" id=\"friendSubmit\" type=\"submit\" value='$cele_jmeno'>   
</form>
```

The PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php                                                             
session_start();
 include('dbconnect.php'); 
  $idprijemce = "";
 if (isset($_GET["idprijemce"])) {    
 }                    
  $_SESSION['idprijemce'] = $idprijemce;    

    $idprihlaseneho = $_SESSION['idprihlaseneho'];

    $vyber = "SELECT zprava FROM chat 
      WHERE IDodesilatel='" . $_SESSION['idprihlaseneho'] . "' AND IDprijemce='" . $_SESSION['idprijemce'] . "' OR IDodesilatel='" . $_SESSION['idprijemce'] . "' AND IDprijemce='" . $_SESSION['idprihlaseneho'] . "' ORDER BY cas ASC";
   $vezmijmeno = "SELECT cele_jmeno FROM uzivatele WHERE ID='". $_SESSION['idprihlaseneho'] ."'";
   $jmeno = mysql_query($vezmijmeno) OR die("Error");

   while($radekjmeno=mysql_fetch_assoc($jmeno)){

     echo ("<b>".$radekjmeno['cele_jmeno'].":</b> <br>"); 
   }


   $result = mysql_query($vyber) OR die("Error: $vyber </br>".mysql_error());
    while($radek = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo ($radek['zprava'] . "<hr><br>");      
}                        

        mysql_close();  

?>
```

**Here is the thing -** I need to display the information from database (taken by the php file) in a div "messages" (on the index page, where are the forms as well), perhaps via AJAX but I dont have necessary skills and I've already spent 2+ hours searching for a solution. The php file works right but it opens a whole new page with the information from DB.

Could You please help me with the AJAX script? Where should I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest implementation would include jQuery (due to different implementation in browsers), here is an example that should work (you need to convert this html and adapt it for php of course - I didn't put escapes/concatenation for php variables .. ):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getAjax(){
    var idprijemce = $('#myForm .friendInput').val();
    var friendSubmit = $('#myForm .friendSubmit').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "messages.php",
        data: {idprijemce:idprijemce,submit:friendSubmit}
    }).done(function( result ) {
        $("#msg").html( result );
        console.log('success');
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id= "myForm" class="friendForm"> 
            <input class="friendInput" type="text" name="idprijemce" value='$idprijemce' hidden>  
            <input class="friendSubmit" id="friendSubmit" type="submit" value='$cele_jmeno' onClick="getAjax();">   
    </form>
    <div id="msg">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see action is removed from the form and added to javascript routine that calls directly the php script, receives the output and then outputs it to div with id="msg".

Comment: Thank you for a constructive reply! It didn't work altough. I think the problem might be in the php file. Shouldn't it return something like "success" for AJAX?

Comment: Nope, ajax can take pure html page or whatever format you send and process it .. Success is based on output headers, so if the server returns 401 error not found that would signalize that call was unsuccessful. One thing you can do is to debug if the php file was called (trough php or javascript itself). I've edited the code and added console.log output (you need to use firefox/chrome and open the console to see the output) .. if you see the message it means that the call was successful. Also you could post any errors found in console if there are some..

Comment: Ok, that's really helpful. Now it works little better than before. There are no errors at all, the script is processing the php file properly. But in the output div there is this "error" Resource id #6 instead of the Messages from DB.

Comment: It looks like you are outputing mysql query instead of the result looking at that string "Resource id #6"